# Post request with axios and redux-thunk in a redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, axios, redux-thunk

I can't figure how to make a post request with axios and redux-thunk so the action is dispatched after the query.

Here's my request module

```js
export default {
    get: function (action, url) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}${url}`)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: action,
                        payload: data
                    });
                });
        };
    },

    post: function (action, url, props) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}${url}`, props)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    return (dispatch) => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: action,
                            payload: data
                        });
                    };
                });
        };

    }
}
```

The GET works. When I call the post function, it enters the function, but never run the returned function.

I tried modifying the order of the functions. I ended up with a working post request, but the action was never dispatched.

```js
post: function (action, url, props) {
        //POST works but action is not dispatched to reducer
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}${url}`, props)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                return (dispatch) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: action,
                        payload: data
                    });
                };
            });
    }
```

Any idea how I can achieve a working post request that gets send to my api and then the response is dispatched to the reducer?

Thank you!

## UPDATE

After extensive testing and back and forth, I think the problem is in redux-form. As pointed by Michael, the dispatch should work. I tested my call in my component with the get method and it doesn't work. Here's my component

```js
const form = reduxForm({
    form: 'LoginPage',
    validate
});

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control" />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>))}
        </div>
    </div>
)

class LoginPage extends Component {
    displayName: 'LoginPage';

    onSubmit(props) {
        login(props.email, props.password);
    }

    render() {

        const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='center-block'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                        <Field name="email" type="email" label='Courriel :' component={renderField} />

                        <Field name="password" type="password" label='Mot de passe :' component={renderField} />

                        <div className="form-group text-center">
                            <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary'>Se connecter</button>
                        </div>
                    </form >
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = 'Required'
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
    }
    if (!values.password) {
        errors.password = 'Required'
    } 4
    return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'LoginPage',
    validate
})(LoginPage);
```

The post request is in the onSubmit method. The login method is called but the return value is never dispatched.

Again, thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my problem. Thanks to Michael for his comment that helped me look in another direction.

The problem was that my form wasn't connected to redux. I ended up adding the connect function to my export statement.

```js
export default connect(null, { login })
    (reduxForm({
        form: 'LoginPage',
        validate
    })(LoginPage));
```

And I also had to change the call to the login function in onSubmit

```js
 onSubmit(props) {
        this.props.login(props.email, props.password);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't add a comment, but I'm glad you figured it out. I'd like to warn you however that on newer versions of redux-form you'll have to decorate your form outside of the connect function to redux. I ran into this problem and it drove me nuts trying to figure it out.

it would be a two step process to connect redux-form after the update. for example, it would look like this.

```
LoginPage = reduxForm({form: 'LoginPage', validate})(LoginPage)
```

and then afterwards your standard connect function

```
export default connect(null, actions)(LoginPage)
```

hope this saves you the headache in the future

Answer (score 0):

your function shouldnt 'return (dispatch)' again, because what the action does is return a function. it should just be

```
function myFunc(action, url) {
 return function (dispatch) {
   axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}${url}`, props)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: action,
        payload: response.data
      })
  })
  }
}
```

edited with full function.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I had in the first place and it doesn't work either. I saw on one site the return next to the dispatch so I tried it.
If I add a console.log right before the axios.post, it is never called in both cases.